# why we assign firefoxdriver instance to webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am novice to Java or Selenium.

I just need help to understand one basic question.

Why we assign firefoxdriver instance to WebDriver?
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver()

I know that this is kind of Late binding in Java, because we can assign IEDriver or some other instance to WebDriver at later point of time.

Question1: But this applices to classes, right?

Question2: WebDriver is an interface, then can we create an object instance of an interface?

Comment: How much do you understand about interfaces? I would suggest you learn the core concepts of the language before you start using Selenium, or indeed doing anything "serious".

Comment: Hi jon, so the reason i mentioned as novice. I know that interfaces are like blueprints of a class and just holds member declarations, where classes which implements this interface provides definitions. I didnt see any instances created for Interfaces. So asking this query.

Comment: Basically, I would suggest ignoring Selenium here - just read the tutorial on interfaces. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

In the above statement, `WebDriver` is an interface. An interface contains empty methods that have been defined but not implemented. These methods can be implemented by anyone as long as the method type and signatures are not violated. Therefore, an interface is also known as contract, because you can use an interface as you like but you cannot change the way it has been defined. And, since it has empty methods you won't actually need to instantiate it and so you cannot instantiate it.

`FirefoxDriver` is a class that has been written specifically for the Firefox browser. It has methods that are implemented and it can be instantiated. It can perform all functions (or methods) on the Firefox browser as defined in the interface `WebDriver`.

So in the above statement, we are actually telling `FirefoxDriver` class that "hey you can automate the various methods that you want on the Firefox browser but you need to stick to the contract defined in `WebDriver`". So we declare a reference variable of type `WebDriver` and then use  it to instantiate `FirefoxDriver`, which means that the object (driver) is of type `WebDriver` but points to the memory allocation to all data and methods in `FirefoxDriver` (and, as mentioned above, the `FirefoxDriver` class already has the implemented version of methods in `WebDriver`). So all good :)

By using this technique, we have made it easy for the tester to use any browser of his or her liking. For example, to automate on IE driver, one will have to simply write a statement like

```
WebDriver driver = new IEDriver(); //where IEDriver is the class written for IE
```

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is simple,

WebDriver is an interface which has a common behavior and we upcast so that the same behavior can be used across the Classes.
Example:

Interface: Consider WebDriver has the behavior of Switch

public interface WebDriver

{

```
void on();

void off();

int voltage=220;;
```

}

Class1: Consider this as ChromeDriver class

public class ChromeDriver implements WebDriver 
{

```
@Override
public void on() {
    System.out.println("ChromeDriver On");

}

@Override
public void off() {
System.out.println("ChromeDriver Off");

}
```

}
Class 2: Consider this class as FireFoxDriver class

public class FireFoxDriver implements WebDriver {

```
@Override
public void on() {
    System.out.println("FireFoxDriver On");

}

@Override
public void off() {
System.out.println("FireFoxDriver Off");

}
```

}

Now Consider Runner Class:

```
//Here to change the implementation we just need to change the object
    //Whether you need to access Mozilla or Chrome
```

public class Runner
{

```
 Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//new FireFoxDriver();
 driver.on();
 driver.off();``
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> I know that this is kind of Late binding in Java,

No. This is an example of compile time binding. But yes, it's also an example of programming to the `WebDriver` interface.

> Question1: But this applies [sic] to classes, right?

It could (conceivably) be an interface that extends `WebDriver`.

> Question2: WebDriver is an interface, then can we create an object instance of an interface?

Yes, you can create concrete instances that implement an interface. In fact, to use any interface there must be at least one concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver is an interface, not a class. We create a Webdriver reference driver and assign it to an object of class FirefoxDriver. To perform the testing on Firefox, make an object of class FirefoxDriver. Likewise, to test on chrome, use Chromedriver class' object and assign it to Webdriver.
Webdriver is an interface which is implemented by both FirefoxDriver class and ChromeDriver class(and classes for other browsers like IE, Safari). 
Objects of only those classes can be assigned to an interface reference which implement that interface(which in this case is Webdriver interface)

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new instance of browser `new ChromeBrowser();` ChromeBrowser(ChromeDriver.exe) is running on local machine and will die with the instance. So the browser restarts with each instance creation. To avoid restart of browser multiple times, Webdriver takes responsibility by referring Browser instance and controls browser not to be restarted for each instance creation.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

[From the documentation;](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html)

> A WebDriver implementation that controls a Chrome browser running on
>   the local machine. This class is provided as a convenience for easily
>   testing the Chrome browser. The control server which each instance
>   communicates with will live and die with the instance. To avoid
>   unnecessarily restarting the ChromeDriver server with each instance,
>   use a RemoteWebDriver coupled with the desired ChromeDriverService,
>   which is managed separately.

Answer (score 0):

**WebDriver** is an interface and **FirefoxDriver** is a class which **implements** this **WebDriver** contract. See Selenium doc    [enter link description here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html)

Now we can create a reference variable of an interface but we can't instantiate any **interface** since it is just a contract to be implemented.But we can assign the instance of a class (In this case FirefoxDriver ) to its Parents(WebDriver).

We can assign child classes to its parents(It may be a **class** or an **interface** to which it extends/implements).

Now The reason behind doing WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver() is just to create an **abstraction** to the client(Java Program) because you can use Any Driver class according to browser.

Answer (score 0):

It will make use of Interface Concept.See the below code.

```
 FirefoxDriver  f = new FirefoxDriver();
 ChromeDriver c = new ChromeDriver();
```

To load a page using chrome,

c.get("google.com");

If I want to use same call with firefox, I need to comment the above line and need to write a new line like this

```
//c.get("google.com");
f.get("google.com");
```

This will go on increasing , ending up with specific code for each instance of driver.
But if I assign the the driver instance to WebDriver interface variable, I can write single set of code  which will work for all drivers.

```
 WebDriver d;
    d  = FireFoxDriver();
    //just replace the above line with d = ChromeDriver() or InternetExplorer();
    d.get("google.com");
    d.getTitle();
    d.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package test.a1;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class testDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String browser="FireFox";
        if(browser=="Chrome")
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\LL\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        }
        else if(browser=="IE")
        {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");

            InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        }
        else if(browser=="FireFox")
        {

            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        }
    }
}
```

We can do this ..so kindly let know why ..we are doing this `Webdriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();`.